# The locus of points of the form $ae^{i\theta}+be^{i\phi}$

Tags: complex-analysis, geometry, circles, locus

Let $a$ and $b\in\mathbb{R}^{>0}$ be two positive real numbers. What is the locus of points of the form $ae^{i\theta}+be^{i\phi}$ where $\theta$ and $\phi\in[-\pi,\pi)$? Does it have any specific name?

Comment: $\theta\neq\phi$. You cannot factor it out.

Comment: Assume $a \ne b$, it will be an [annulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annulus_%28mathematics%29)

Comment: @achillehui That's what I was looking for. Thanks for your comment. May I ask you to post it as the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WLOG, $a\le b$. $$ae^{i\theta}$$ is a circle centered at the origin and of radius $a$.

Now the sum

$$ae^{i\theta}+be^{i\phi}$$ corresponds to a circle of radius $b$, the center of which is swept along the first circle. Hence the locus is a filled ring of inner diameter $a-b$ and outer diameter $a+b$. (See @achille's comment.)